# Is $J:X \rightarrow X^{**}$ an injection?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X$
is a Banach Space and $X^{**}$
is the bidual, $J:X \rightarrow X^{**}$
is the canonical map from $X$
to $X^{**}$.
Is this map an injection?

I know that i know that for it to be injectiv we have :

for all $x,y \in X$ with $J(x)=J(y) \Rightarrow x=y$ so:

$J(x)=J(y)$ then for all $f \in X^*$ $J(x)(f)=J(y)(f) \Rightarrow f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow A$

Now f Is any linear functional on $X$. Is this enough to show that $x=y$ ? And if so does this mean that J is injectiv even if not reflexive ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: yes, it is an injection.